# CGI binary does not execute, instead gets downloaded

Tags: apache-2.4, cgi

I have an apache 2.4.46-3 server, which serves out of /srv/http. I have a folder /srv/http/bin with 2 files:

**.htacces** (mode 644):

```
AddHandler cgi-script .exe
Options +ExecCGI
```

**main.exe** (mode 755): compiled from main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
   cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
   cout << "<html>\n";
   cout << "<head>\n";
   cout << "<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>\n";
   cout << "</head>\n";
   cout << "<body>\n";
   cout << "<h2>Hello World! This is my first CGI program</h2>\n";
   cout << "</body>\n";
   cout << "</html>\n";
   
   return 0;
}
```

But when I visit the page localhost/bin/main.exe, it offers to download the exe instead of displaying the html. Did I forget to enable something?

## edit:

[Problem with cgi-bin directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/308142/problem-with-cgi-bin-directory)
this did NOT solve my issue!

Replacing all instances of `exe` with `cgi` also did not solve my issue!

Adding

```
<Directory "/srv/http/bin">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl exe
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To httpd.conf also did NOT solve the issue! There are no errors in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` related to cgis or exes or the /srv/http/bin folder, so what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did not have the cgi module loaded in httpd.conf.

Here is the relevant configuration (search for "cgi_module" in your config):

```
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
        LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
```